# i want to know the name of a table

Tags: furniture

[image] i want to buy a table like this, but I don't know the name. Somebody help?

Comment: Asking for a brand recommendation or where to buy is off topic. HOWEVER this question might have value if accompanied by an answer that explains why the questor is unlikely to be able to buy a table like this at all, and recommends that he custom modify a standard table to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a "desk with two short legs". :-)

I'd guess it might have been custom made or adapted from something normal by having two of its legs shortened with a saw.

- [Ikea Hacks](http://www.ikeahackers.net/about/)
- [Ikea ADILS/HISSMON](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/desks/table-tops-legs/adils-hissmon-table-cashew-nut-shaped-white-spr-09005932/)